# Elementary Numerical Analysis2

Tags: numerical-methods

Just wanted to confirm my answer here again:

Q: Evaluate $$p(x)=1-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}-\frac{x^9}{9!}+\frac{x^{12}}{12!}-\frac{x^{15}}{15!}$$ as efficiently as possible.  How many multiplications are necessarY?  Assume all coefficients have been computed and stored for later use.

My answer: $u=x^3$ and evaluate:
$$p(u)=1-\frac{u}{6}+\frac{u^2}{720}-\frac{u^3}{362880}+\frac{u^4}{479001600}-\frac{u^5}{1307674368000}$$
Necessary Multiplications: $6$.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Notice that $6!=(6\cdot 5\cdot 4)\cdot 3!$, so you can do better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
y = x^3/6
$$

$$
p(x)=1-y \left(1 - \frac{y}{20} \left(1 - \frac{y}{84} \left(1 -\frac{y}{220} \left(1 - \frac{y}{455}\right)\right)\right)
 \right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

You would need a few less multiplications if you apply Horner's rule. See for example, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polynomial.html .